# Convert String to Secret key in java

Tags: java, file, encryption, secret-key

I have encrypted my file using DES algorithm and Stored tat DES Secretkey into database converting it into String.
Now i want to Convert that String to Secretkey.

Here is the code.

```
        secret_key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
        alogrithm_specs = new IvParameterSpec(initialization_vector);
        // set encryption mode ...
        encrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret_key, alogrithm_specs);
        //out.print("actual secret_key:"+secret_key);

        String keyString = encoder.encode(secret_key.getEncoded());
        //out.print("keyString:"+keyString);

        byte[] encodedKey = decoder.decodeBuffer(keyString);
        //out.print("byte[]:"+encodedKey);

        secret_key= new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey,0,encodedKey.length, "DES");
        //out.print("after encode & decode secret_key:"+secret_key);
```

Above code will convert String into key as below:

```
actual secret_key: 'com.sun.crypto.provider.DESKey@1807c'

keyString:hvsCa0XcXhY=

byte[]:[B@7c91fe

after encode & decode secret_key:'javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@1807c`
```

I want to Store that Secretkey into database by converting the key into String.
Then while decrypting i want convert that String back to Key.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you are expecting with the code? _"But i want to Convert String to SecretKey as actual secretkey"_ is not entirely clear here

Comment: First i converted DES Secretkey to String for storing in Database. Now I want to Convert that String to DES Secretkey.

Comment: Can you also provide the code where you declare 'ecoder' and 'decoder'?

Comment: What you are printing is the string representation of the objects rather than their content. For example, instead of `out.print("byte[]:"+encodedKey);` you should use `out.print("byte[]: " + Arrays.toString(encodedKey));`...

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the object class and the hashcodes of 2 different instances sharing the same reference. If you want to confirm whether your key is getting decoded correctly, print the encoded version of the decoded key.

```
System.out.println("after encode & decode secret_key:" + Base64.encodeBase64String(secretKey.getEncoded()));
```

Here is the modified source which might help you confirm the keys are infact the same (please note I didn't have ecoder and decoder declarations available in your code above hence used a standard Base64):

```
SecretKey secretKey;
        String stringKey;
        try {
            secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();
            // byte[] initialization_vector;
            // IvParameterSpec alogrithm_specs = new
            // IvParameterSpec(initialization_vector);
            // set encryption mode ...
            Cipher encrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

            if (secretKey != null) {
                stringKey = Base64.encodeBase64String(secretKey.getEncoded());
                System.out.println("actual secret_key:" + stringKey);

                byte[] encodedKey = Base64.decodeBase64(stringKey);

                // out.print("byte[]:"+encodedKey);

                secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, 0, encodedKey.length,
                        "DES");
                System.out.println("after encode & decode secret_key:"
                        + Base64.encodeBase64String(secretKey.getEncoded()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Outputs in both the sops are identical:

```
actual secret_key:dYBRc0Ok6dk=
after encode & decode secret_key:dYBRc0Ok6dk=
```

Comment: Ok. While i decrypt the file it throws "Invalid Key Exception".

Comment: Hmm, Invalid Key Exception might be because of different reasons - due to IvParameterSpec initialization and so on. The above method will just help you verify if the key you have stored and recreated is infact a valid one. I would suggest to open a new question with the stacktrace of the Invalid Key Exception and we'll take it from there? :)

Comment: You may want to close this question by either accepting the answer or editing your question to denote [solved]. Good luck!